# Mapping conflict when deploying with spring boot Jersey starter deployed as WAR

Tags: spring-boot, war, jersey-2.0, tomcat8

We're using Spring Boot with its Jersey Starter and deploy it as a WAR, programmatically deployed into another application's embedded Tomcat.

After our application startup, **in some environments**, a mapping conflict occurs and is logged as follows:

```
o.g.j.s.i.JerseyServletContainerInitializer : Mapping conflict. A Servlet registration exists with same mapping as the Jersey servlet application, named com.vidal.pmsi.config.PmsiResourceConfiguration, at the servlet mapping, /*.
```

The resource configuration is as follows:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
@ExposedApplication
@Component
public class PmsiResourceConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

   public PmsiResourceConfiguration() {
      packages("com.vidal.pmsi.api");
      packages("com.vidal.pmsi.config");
      property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);
      property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
   }
}
```

As far as I understand, Spring Boot Jersey Starter will register a 'jerseyServlet'-named servlet mapping to '/*'.

**In some environments**, Jersey's own `JerseyServletContainerInitializer` will trigger after `SpringApplication` startup, failing to register `PmsiResourceConfiguration` because of the existing `jerseyServlet` mapping.

This is a problem because of our own open-source library that tries (and crashes at) getting the context path at startup:

```java
// compile-time generated Linkers.java
@WebListener
@Generated("fr.vidal.oss.jax_rs_linker.LinkerAnnotationProcessor")
public final class Linkers implements ServletContextListener {
    private static String contextPath = "";
    private static String applicationName = ApplicationName.get();

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
         //applicationName = FQCN of PmsiResourceConfiguration
        contextPath = ContextPaths.contextPath(sce.getServletContext(), applicationName);
    }

    // [...]
}
// ContextPaths.java
public static String contextPath(ServletContext servletContext, String registeredKey) {
    // registeredKey is therefore the FQCN of PmsiResourceConfiguration
    String mappedPath = stripWildcard(servletContext.getServletRegistration(registeredKey).getMappings().iterator().next());
    return servletContext.getContextPath() + mappedPath;
}
```

The last snippet of code will fail as there is no mapping for the registered resource configuration class (there is only one for `'jerseyServlet'` key).

This does *not* fail when there isn't any mapping conflict reported. 
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running my head against a similar problem where I have a Spring Boot Application with a Jersey JAX-RS Webservice. Everything worked fine when using the embeddedTomcat but it went to hell when I tried deploying the war on a regular Tomcat of the same version (Tomcat8).

The problem is that by default the embeddedTomcat does not scan for ServletContainerInitializer in jar files, yet the regular one does and that conflicted with the ServletContainer/Config that Spring sets up.

Apart from excluding the jar containing the `JerseyServletContainerInitializer` I found an option to tell tomcat to filter out this particular ServletContainerInitializer (SCI). Setting the [containerSciFilter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) attribute on the context helped:

```
<Context containerSciFilter="JerseyServletContainerInitializer">
...
</Context>
```

I did not define any SCI in my META-INF/services but the jar that contains the JerseySCI has defined it and it was on the right path to be found by Tomcat.

---

Considering that this was the closest matchinb question and without an answer I don't repost my question and try to answer this one as I believe that the cause is the same.